# Netbeans x Firefox : Could not access the url through the external browser

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I've been using Netbeans with Firefox without problems for months.

But yesterday Firefox crashed and i had to reinstall it.

Firefox was sucesfully installed and it's working ok. But now when i try to run any project in Netbeans, i get the infamous "could not access the url through the external browser" error.

How to fix it ? My work is stopped for hours because this bug.

Please help !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 20):

goto Netbeans Tools->option->General->Web Browser  selection list & then select any one of available  web browsers

Answer (score 2):

I could fix this problem by running Netbeans as administrator (on Windows 8.1).

Comment: This worked for me. My company is going through an ownership transfer and a lot of security settings are being applied by corporate admins. What was launching before just fine now requires this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must update JAVA PLUGIN

Answer (score 0):

> Tools->Options->General->Web Browser selection list & then select any
> one of available web browsers.

That's will resolve the issue.